# PHP Populating a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make an array in this type of format

```
Array
(
    [name] => 'Nick'
    [email] => 'nick@email.com'
    [groups] => Array (
        [0] => 'group1'
        [1] => 'group2'
        [2] => 'group3'
    )
)
```

name and email will contain one value.  groups will contain multiple values (different for all people).

So I am in a loop defined like so

```
foreach($result as $info) {

}
```

Now the $info variable contains a lot of data, about lots of users.  To get the name and email of each user, I can do

```
$name = $info["name"][0];
$email = $info["email"][0];
```

I can then start building the array I am attempting to make

```
$userData = array(
    "name" => $name,
    "email" => $email
);
```

To get the groups, I need to do

```
foreach($info["group"] as $group) {
    print_r($group["name"]);    
}
```

My code at the moment looks like the following
$userData = array();

```
foreach($result as $info) {

    $name = $info["disName"][0];
    $email = $info["email"][0];

    $userData = array(
        "name" => $name,
        "email" => $email
    );

    foreach($info["group"] as $group) {
        print_r($group["name"]);
    }

}
```

How can I get this data I am extracting into an Array in the format I need?

Thanks

Comment: Well what's the output you are getting with the current code?

Comment: `$userData = array("name" => $name, "email" => $email, "groups" => $info["group"]["name"]);` won't do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code..

```
foreach($result as $info) {

    $name = $info["disName"][0];
    $email = $info["email"][0];

    $userData = array(
        "name" => $name,
        "email" => $email
    );

    foreach($info["group"] as $group) {
        $groups[] = $group;
    }

    $userData['group'] = $groups;

}
```

`$groups` is an array for index `$userData['group']`

Comment: What's the difference between your last `foreach` and simply `$userData['group'] = $info['group']` ?